# Selenium: How can I validate an element by an XPath expression WITHOUT throwing an exception if not found?

Tags: selenium, xpath

The code I'd like to be using is as follows:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath_here")
    // Call reporting function and say the element was found
else
{   // Call reporting function and say the element was Not found
    // then continue so I can implement my own code if it isn't found
}
```

There is more to it than just doing the work in the above Else in the catch{} block instead.

I've tried using .isDisplayed() and findElements... >= 0. Both those also throw an exception when the element isn't found.

Side question: Why wouldn't these functions just be built to return a Boolean value?

Comment: Why on earth would they return a boolean? `FindElement`'s job is not to tell you if something is there or not. There are various states of "being there".

Comment: I should have rephrased my side question. Makes sense to me that findElement returns the element if found (and not bool), but I feel like there should be an alternative function similar to findElement that returns a true if the mechanism behind findElement finds the element, or a false if it does not. That way we could report whether or not it was found and continue testing for more elements/what have you - since to me that seems like a pretty basic thing testers would want to do. Regardless, the solution in the answer suffices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findElements()`, and test to see if the length is greater than 0:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//xpath_here")).size() > 0)
     //call reporting function and say the element was found     
else
{     //call reporting function and say the element was Not found
      //then continue so I can implement my own code if it isn't found
}
```

`findElements()` will not throw an exception if there aren't any elements. It will return a list of length 0.

Comment: Won't this throw an exception if the xpath isn't found?

Comment: @user1599401 I edited the original answer, but basically:  No.  `findElements()` will not throw an exception; it will either return a list of found elements, or return a list of length 0.

Comment: The call to .findElements wont throw an exception but what you do inside the if block certainly could, epecially if the implicit wait is at the default of 0 , not giving the page enough time to finish loading.  So, doing it this way is no guarantee of page readiness.